# Unknown error in CREATE statement when using column constraint

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to create `SQLite` table using `System.Data.SQLite` library under `.NET Framework 4.7.2` with statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_accessibility (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'lk3' CHECK (name IN ('lk3', 'api', 'err')),
    created TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT datetime('now'),
    notified INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK (notified IN (0, 1)),
    closed TEXT,
    id_sm TEXT
 );
```

and getting an error:

> SQL logic error
> near "(": syntax error

How to fix this proplem? `SQLite` version: 3.32.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DEFAULT operator with parentheses when using with expression:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_accessibility (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'lk3' CHECK (name IN ('lk3', 'api', 'err')),
    created TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now')),
    notified INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK (notified IN (0, 1)),
    closed TEXT,
    id_sm TEXT
);
```

See [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint).